# Scale up the TextView on first Touch, scale down on second touch

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, textview

I am comparatively new to Android.

Description -

I have a `LinearLayout` with `TextView`'s in it.
I am adding the `TextView` dynamically.

When I touch the `TextView`, I want it to `ScaleUp` and when I touch the same `TextView` again I want it to `ScaleDown`.

My problems are -

1. When a `TextView` is `scaled up` and any other `TextView` is `touched`. The older `TextView` should `scale down` and the new `touched` `TextView` should `scale up`.
2. When I touch a `scaled up` `TextView` then this `TextView` should scale down.

**This is what I have tried**

I have 2 set xmls. 1 for scale up

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <scale
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="3.0"
    android:toYScale="3.0" >
</scale>
```

and the other for scale down

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <scale
    android:fromXScale="3.0"
    android:fromYScale="3.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" >
</scale>
```

My `Activity` class -

```
myTextView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if (myTextView.getAnimation() == null) {
                        Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                                getBaseContext(), R.anim.scale_up);
                        a.setFillAfter(true);
                        v.startAnimation(a);
                    } else {
                        v.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onTouch(View v1,
                                    MotionEvent event) {
                                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                                    Animation a1 = AnimationUtils
                                            .loadAnimation(
                                                    getBaseContext(),
                                                    R.anim.scale_down);
                                    a1.setFillAfter(true);
                                    v1.startAnimation(a1);

                                }
                                return true;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }

        });
```

Comment: every time a textview gets scaled: store a reference  of the current textview/state. every time a new touch event occurs: check the state of the current textview and do your actions appropriate to the use cases you have given

Comment: Thanks but the problem is I am not able to store the reference. I even tried adding a TextView in my LinerLayout and set that TextView's visibility to 0 an I then use the height and width of this hidden TextView to match in the first if inside OnTouch. Still onTouch it always enters the else part.

Comment: give every textview an id by using the setTag method, now you know which textview is which.. then make an collection of textviews and store states in them.. on every touch you loop this collection and search for the right textview and do appropriate things with it. You should rethink the implementation of handling the touch event.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Could you move this as an answer? Also could you tell me of any better way to handle the touch event. Also each item in the list has a Image on the left, some text on the right and 0 to 2 links. Which view should i use or should it be a collection of views in a layout and then I have a list of layouts.

Comment: The animations your are using are ViewAnimations. These animations can  be used to animate views and viewgroups. So instead of calling the animation on a textview you can call it on a layout. Are you using a listview or ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make an collection of textviews and store states in them.. on every touch you loop this collection and search for the right textview and do appropriate things with it. You can also search trough this collection and check which textviews are scaled up or down since you are managing the states yourself.